# How can I make my onclick event select the id of the element that was clicked using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The only links I was able to find that were relevant were using jQuery and I'm trying to stick with JavaScript for now.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Chat.css">
    <script src="TTT.js"></script>
    <title>'Tic Tac Toe'</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="game">

    <button type="button" class="row1 block" name="one"></button>
    <button type="button" class="row1 block" name="two"></button>
    <button type="button" class="row1 block" name="three"></button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="row2 block" name="four"></button>
    <button type="button" class="row2 block" name="five"></button>
    <button type="button" class="row2 block" name="six"></button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="row3 block" name="seven"></button>
    <button type="button" class="row3 block" name="eight"></button>
    <button type="button" class="row3 block" name="nine"></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I basically want this function to see which button name was selected and change classes to indicate this selection.

```
var  buttons= document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var number=(element.attr('name'));
        document.getElementsByName(number).onclick
        var chosenblock=document.getElementsByName(number);
        chosenblock.classList.toggle('chosen');
    });
}
```

This is the JavaScript I have right now. Does the `.onclick` need to be there if the event listener was already added above? Beyond that, how can I make this click toggle my class `chosen`. I'm just kind of confused by the set up in general.

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/43L4rku3/). Also, if you want to give me pointers on making this tic-tac-toe game, feel free (first project since codecademy, it definitely makes you feel like it teaches you more than it actually does). Anyway, thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few things...

First

```
var  buttons= document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        var number=(element.attr('name'));
        document.getElementsByName(number).onclick
        var chosenblock=document.getElementsByName(number);
        chosenblock.classList.toggle('chosen');
    });
}
```

This line

```
var number=(element.attr('name'));
```

Where does `element` come from? From nowhere. If you are sticking to pure javascript, you should use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

*this* makes reference to the element itself which was clicked, then you use `getAttribute` to get its name

```
    var number=this.getAttribute('name');

    // [0] will return the first element since .getElementsByName returns an array
    var chosenblock=document.getElementsByName(number)[0];
```

Later you have this

```
document.getElementsByName(number).onclick
```

First, it should be [.click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) not `onclick`, but you have your code inside an EventListener listening to clicks, so... you don't need it! :D!

Keep moving...

Your first statement is this one

```
if (chosenblock.classList.contains('chosen'){
    return false;
}
```

You missed a `)`! Just add it like this

```
if (chosenblock.classList.contains('chosen')) // <-- :D !
{
    return false;
}
```

What about the other if statements?

```
    if (computerchoice >= 0 && < 1) {
        compselected('one');
    }
```

Do you see what's wrong in there? Your statement should say : *if computerchoice is greater than or equal to zero and computerchoice is less than one*

So you fix it adding `computerchoice` after the `&`

```
    if (computerchoice >= 0 && computerchoice < 1) {
        compselected('one');
    }
```

That simple! *(Note: do that in all of your if statements, they are all wrong)*

And finally you have a `};` causing troubles :(, we should kill it! Nah, just remove it.

If you didn't understand anything, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmku0dx/1/) with the corrections above.

I hope it helps you :P

**UPDATE**

I didn't see the problem in the CSS :3

This is what you have

```
.chosen {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    border:2px solid black;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    padding-top:5px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    .chosen:before{   /* This should be outside! */
        content: "X"
    }
}
```

See that you are enclosing `.chosen:before {...}` inside of `.chosen {...}`? Just move it outside!

```
.chosen {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    border:2px solid black;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    padding-top:5px;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}

.chosen:before{
    content: "X"
}
```

I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmku0dx/2/) as well

Enjoy! :D

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you, if this was reddit I would give you gold lol. Is there a SO equivalent? Either way you made this much more clear for me, thanks for your time Eric.

Comment: No problema amigo! Glad to help you :D

Comment: Also what do you think about this in the CSS for adding an X tot the block when selected? It doesn't seem to be working? .chosen:before{
    content: "X"}. I want it to switch classes and add this text at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is something like this:

```
var  buttons= document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var chosenblock=e.target;
        if (chosenblock.className.match(' chosen')) {
            chosenblock.className.replace(' chosen','');
        } else {
            chosenblock.className += (' chosen');
        }
    });
}
```

You don't need .onclick since you've already added a ClickEventListener to the elements.The code assumes that you may have other classes associated with the buttons (thus the space before 'chosen'). Also, the function receives an EventElement e, from which you can get which button was targeted.

Comment: Isn't the first part of the if statement replacing the chosen class with another class?

Comment: You mean .replace()? It replaces the string ' chosen' with a blank string, effectively deleting ' chosen' from the className string.

Answer (score 0):

For your click operation you've written so much code.
rather than try this simplified code

```
 $( ".block" ).bind( "click", function() {
 if($(this).hasClass("chosen"))
 {$(this).removeClass("chosen"); }
   else
   {$(this).addClass("chosen");}
});
```

find the updated http://jsfiddle.net/8qmku0dx/5/
I am not good at CSS so tried only on code